# RadioGroup is not being referenced

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Radio Group in Android Eclipse in activity_main.xml . But, when I try to reference the RadioGroup in a Java class, but Eclipse doesn't recognise it. It's not a problem of referencing activity_main, because TextView are being referenced correctly.
I'm using Mac Maverick, Eclipse.

This is my RadioGroup code:

```
<RadioGroup 
     android:id="@+id/types">
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/take_out"
     android:text="Take-Out"
     />
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/sit_down"
     android:text="Sit-Down"
     />
     <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delivery"
     android:text="Delivery"
     />
 </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

we use type="button" because type="radio" makes it impossible to give the element a background image or style the element differently in any way - it will always look like the browser's default radio button.I hope this answer will help..

You can use the classes provided by the framework to style the checked radio button. For example:
Code:

```
.x-form-cb-checked .x-form-radio {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But, how should I change my code? Where should I insert the type tag?